# KeyError using format with python

Tags: python-3.x, string, format

I'm new in python and i'm getting this error while trying to run my code

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-74e7a7ea82f3> in <module>
----> 1 SEARCH['profession']['call'].format('Jhon',23)

KeyError: '"sea'
```

This is my code, I am trying to use the format in a string that simulates a dictionary

```
SEARCH = {
    'profession' : {"call":'{"sea:searchProfession":{"datasheet": {"name":{},"age": {}}}}'},
    'id' : {"call":'{"sea:searchId":{"personId": {"id":{},"name": {},"age":"{}"}}}'},
}

SEARCH['profession']['call'].format('Jhon',23)
```

I know there are similar issues, but I have not found the solution

Comment: The other curly brackets are being confused for replacement fields, so you should change which string formatting method you're using (eg. [template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) or C-style formatting).

Comment: Do you control `SEARCH`? If you do I would use it as a full nested `dict` and then when I need the text use `json.dumps()` on whatever part I needed.